# RxJava timeout and kill underlying thread

Tags: timeout, rx-java, rx-java2

We are doing a simple `timeout()` call on a `Flowable`.

```
Flowable.fromCallable(() -> callToExternalService())
       .timeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

The timeout itself works fine, but we noticed that the timed out call `callToExternalService`, which sometimes could take minutes, even if it is discarded, doesn't free up the thread where it is running on, until it completes fully, and by doing so it's wasting resources. In our case, if the call times out, the thread can be killed straightaway, and so it shouldn't wait for the call to finish.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: can you add `callToExternalService` code ?

Comment: hi @bubbles , I am confused on why would that matter for this particular question? It's a call to an external API.

Comment: You want to free up the thread used in `callToExternalService` when the timeout appears ?

Comment: not inside, there's not a thread created inside `callToExternalService`. In my understanding, RxJava will use a thread from the computation Scheduler to call `callToExternalService`, and if the RxJava timeout happens, the flowable continues, but RxJava currently is keeping the thread used to call `callToExternalService` until it finishes, instead of freeing up the thread straightaway for further use (has it has no use, it timed out and the result will not be used).

Comment: *...the flowable continues, but RxJava currently is keeping the thread used to call callToExternalService...* !! how you know this ?

Comment: @bubbles by monitoring the JVM

Answer (score 0):

Add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` (or some other scheduler) before the `.timeout`

Comment: I should have added this to the question, it's running on the IO schedule already